# Make [StackExp] instance of Expr class

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I make class `Expr` for arithmetic operations

```
class Expr a where
  mul :: a -> a -> a 
  add :: a -> a -> a
  lit :: Integer -> a
```

i want to "parse" something like this: mul ( add (lit 3) (lit 2)) (lit 4) = (3+2)*4

and i have data type:

```
data StackExp = PushI Integer
              | PushB Bool
              | Add
              | Mul
              | And
              | Or
                deriving Show
```

and

```
type Program = [StackExp] --i use this type for function of stack calculator later
```

my task is: i need to make instance of `Expr` for type `Program`

more concrete - i want to make this transformation:
`mul ( add (lit 3) (lit 2)) (lit 4)` ->>> `[PushI 2, PushI 3, Add, PushI 4, Mul]`

i have problems because i receive `[[StackExp]]` at the output of my instance declaration.

my try:

```
instance Expr Program where
  lit n = (PushI n):[]
  add exp1 exp2 = exp1:(exp2:[Add]) 
  mul exp1 exp2 = exp1:(exp2:[Mul])
```

i don't know how to concatenate all sub-expressions into list

----------------  compiler error looks like this------------------------

```
Couldn't match type `[StackExp]' with `StackExp'
    Expected type: StackExp
      Actual type: Program
```

..........

Comment: sorry, i think i solve problem just now:  add exp1 exp2 = exp1 ++ exp2 ++ [Add] 
  mul exp1 exp2 = exp1 ++ exp2 ++ [Mul]

Comment: If it works you can answer your own question so this one won't still look unsolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what you basically want to do is you want to compile from the abstract syntax of your expression language (the type class `Expr`) to code for a simple stack machine (a list of elements of type `StackExpr`).

One problem that you immediately run into then is that, in just Haskell 98 or Haskell 2010, you cannot declare `[StackExpr]` an instance of a class. For example, GHC will complain with

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Expr [StackExp]'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Expr [StackExp]'
```

To work your way around this, you could define `Program` as a type isomorphism (rather than as a mere type synonym as you have now):

```
newtype Program = P [StackExp] deriving Show
```

and then make Program an instance of the class Expr. (Alternatively, you could enable `FlexibleInstances` as suggested by the error message above.)

Now we can write the required instance declaration:

```
instance Expr Program where
  mul (P x) (P y) = P (x ++ y ++ [Mul])
  add (P x) (P y) = P (x ++ y ++ [Add])
  lit n           = P [PushI n]
```

That is, for multiplication and addition, we first compile the operands and then produce, respectively, the `Mul` or `Add` instruction; for literals we produce the corresponding push instruction.

With this declaration, we get, for your example:

```
> mul (add (lit 3) (lit 2)) (lit 4) :: Program
P [PushI 3,PushI 2,Add,PushI 4,Mul]
```

(Not quite as in your example. You swap the order of the operands to `Add`. As addition is commutative, I will assume that this version is acceptable as well.)

---

Of course it is more fun to also write a small evaluator for stack programs:

```
eval :: Program -> [Integer]
eval (P es) = go es []
  where
    go [] s                   = s
    go (PushI   n : es) s     = go es (n : s)
    go (Add : es) (m : n : s) = go es ((m + n) : s)
    go (Mul : es) (m : n : s) = go es ((m * n) : s)
```

(Note that I am ignoring instructions that deal with Booleans here as you only seem to deal with integer expressions anyway.)

Now we have, for your example,

```
> eval (mul (add (lit 3) (lit 2)) (lit 4))
[20]
```

which seems about right.

Comment: thank you for your answer. and yes, i enable Flexible Instances because GHCi compiler advice me to do so =).